# Objects invisible in the rendered viewport and render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I'm using blender 2.81 and I'm reasonably new to blender so I was following CG Geek's forest tutorial. Anyways, eventually I noticed that some of my objects weren't appearing in the rendered viewport so I rendered the whole thing and they didn't appear in the render either. I checked object properties and I have all the visibility and ray visibility settings enabled. The objects to catch and cast shadows, they just don't appear. I've done some research (for anyone else with similar problems this might help: [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up)) on why this might be the case and here is the things I've checked so they're probably not the issue, and also some things to note.

- The material alpha is 1 (maximum)
- The objects that were invisible are visible in Eevee
- The node connection in the compositor is connected (number two on the list in the link above)
- I'm not on the wrong scene/layer (I only have one of each)
- I'm not too close for the objects to be clipping
- The camera icon that allow rendering is enabled
- I don't have a material that disables camera visibility
- It's not something to do with depth of field in the camera
- The camera, not another object is the active camera
- The objects do have faces
- I did save my file as a .blend and that didn't work (I think that maybe thats what caused it to break)
- The objects don't have a particle system with emitter visibility disabled
- I am not using local view
- The object is not hidden
- The objects appear every other mode of the 3D viewport

Here is a screenshot of one of the invisible objects (a tree) you can see it's outline here but not in the render. The trees in the background are part of the HDR
[image]

Comment: One more thing, I opened a new file and appended the objects from the old file to the new file and the problem persists. Same thing with duplicating the file.

Comment: Seems there's no light. Add a Light to the scene.

Comment: Probably should have said this in the original post but this is a duplicate, the original took way too much time to load so for this I used a duplicate, the original has a light
EDIT: Also, doesn't a HDR already provide a light source?

Comment: Let's wait for more expertized answers but could the night image be just so dark that the object hardly is visible?

Comment: Have you got any compositor passes set up that may interfere from another file? Do you have alpha hashed or blend turned on? Recalculated normals?

Comment: Hello :). To make it easier for others to help you, consider [sharing the .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).